# React data export to excel (xls)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, react-admin

I want to export certain set of data to excel in react. But some of the cells needs to have custom style, and document itself is in certain structure that needs to be followed. What are good libraries in react that you would recommend to achieve this. The library should only be for exporting data to xls and cells needs to be customizable. Also if possible to be able to create more than one sheet. That are the basic requirements, nothing more nothing less. If there aren't any then if someone can point me in right way to achieve this with vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `excel4node` library so you can add your own style to each cell easily.
Here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node) to this library

This is some usage of this library:

```
// Require library
var xl = require('excel4node');
 
// Create a new instance of a Workbook class
var wb = new xl.Workbook();
 
// Add Worksheets to the workbook
var ws = wb.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');
var ws2 = wb.addWorksheet('Sheet 2');
 
// Create a reusable style
var style = wb.createStyle({
  font: {
    color: '#FF0800',
    size: 12,
  },
  numberFormat: '$#,##0.00; ($#,##0.00); -',
});
 
// Set value of cell A1 to 100 as a number type styled with paramaters of style
ws.cell(1, 1)
  .number(100)
  .style(style);
```